# Why my app does not work on the new Galaxy s23 ultra?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, samsung-mobile

I have created an app and published on google play
I used to debug and fix the app by Huawei mate 20 pro  it worked very fine but after publishing the app I downloaded it on Samsung galaxy s20 and s23 ultra the app half worked on s20(some library attached to my app did not work) but with s23 ultra even the simple button did not work ( I add a click listener to it) when I press the button nothing happens

this is my app link on Google Play
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aziz.mediadownloader

minSdk 24
targetSdk 34

thank you in advance

I expect the app to work fine on new devices as an old one!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.